# How do I save a facebook profile picture using NSURLSession?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm just creating a simple facebook login application, in my viewdidload() method, i have the permissions and I'm getting the name,username,email-id and profile picture link, but what i want to do is try and download that link(URL) and save/download it locally.

Just started using x-code and any help would be appreciated.

```
> - (void)viewDidLoad {
>     
>      [super viewDidLoad];    
>     FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];    loginButton.center = self.view.center;    [loginButton
> setDelegate:self];
>     loginButton.loginBehavior=FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;
>         [self.view addSubview:loginButton];
>     loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile",@"email",@"user_friends",@"user_about_me",@"user_friends",@"user_birthday",@"user_hometown"];
>     loginButton.publishPermissions=@[@"publish_actions"];
>     FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result;
>     
>     
> 
>     {
>         if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]) {
>             NSLog(@"%@",result);
>         }
>     }
> 
>     NSMutableDictionary* param = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
>     [param setValue:@"id,name,email,picture.width(100).height(100),bio"
> forKey:@"fields"];
> 
> 
>     NSURL *profilePictureURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/user/picture?type=large"]];
>                                                       NSURLRequest *profilePictureURLRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:profilePictureURL
> cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10.0f];
> // Facebook profile picture cache policy: Expires in 2 weeks
>     [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:profilePictureURLRequest delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `NSURLSessionDataTask` task with your `NSURLRequest`:

```
NSURL *profilePictureURL = ...;
NSURLRequest *profilePictureURLRequest = ...;

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:profilePictureURLRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    // This block is called when the request completes / fails.

    if ((!error) && (data.length > 0)) {

        // Write to local URL on background thread.
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

            NSURL *someFileUrl = ...;

            [data writeToUrl:someFileUrl atomically:YES];

        });
    }
}];

// Send the request...
[task resume];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will save Image in application document directory.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
                    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=normal",[result objectForKey:@"id"]]]];
                    [imageData writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/profilePic.jpg",[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]] atomically:YES];
                })
```